# Продумывание логики "Морского боя"

Tags: java, логика

Здравствуйте. Собираюсь писать Морской бой для Android и вот начал, как правило, с логики. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, верно ли я рассуждаю. Мультиплеер. Игра на одном устройстве.

Расстановка кораблей сводится к созданию двух `ArrayList`, один для кораблей, другой для ячеек (с вложенным `ArrayList`), а именно:

Создаю класс `Ship` для корабля. В конструктор передаётся количество его палуб и индексы его ячеек. В классе находится `shotCounter` - счётчик подбитых палуб. Реализован метод `shot` в котором инкрементируется этот счетчик. Метод меняет состояния ячеек на `KILL` и возвращает `true` если корабль полностью потоплен и `false`, если только подбит. При расстановке кораблей создаётся `List` из классов `Ship`. Причем, каждой ячейке, относившейся к кораблю передаётся индекс этого корабля из `List`-а. Так обеспечивается взаимная связь корабля со своими ячейками.

Создаю класс `Cell` для ячейки игрового поля. Класс имеет два конструктора. В первый передается, как описано выше, индекс корабля из `List`-а, к которому относится ячейка. Класс будет содержать переменную с индексом корабля, логическую переменную `IS_EMPTY`, если ячейка не относится ни к какому кораблю и состояние ячейки (`MISS` - промах, `HIT` - подбит и `KILL` - потоплен. Во второй ничего не передается. В нем логической переменной `IS_ЕMPTY` присваивается `true`. В классе `Cell` будет написан метод `shot` без входных параметров со следующей логикой. Если `IS_ЕМPTY` содержит `true`, то менять состояние ячейки на `MISS` (промах). Иначе следует обратиться к соответствующему классу `Ship`, вызвав его метод `shot`. Если он вернет `false`, то меняем состояние ячейки на `HIT`. Если `true`, то значит корабль подбит полностью и следует автоматически поменять состояния вблиз лежащих ячеек на `MISS`, так как там ничего быть не может, скорее всего удобнее это сделать в классе `Ship` так как он будет хранить ячейки своего корабля.

Описывать дальше не буду, а то вам читать не захочется. Жду критики, может кто-нибудь обнаружит подводные камни заранее :)

Comment: Я делал так: матрица бутит, где тру - занятая, фалс свободная ячейка; еще одна матрица где попадания, тру - стреляный, фалс - не стреляный сектор. Наложением сравниваю...

Comment: А как же палубы? В игре буду выводить счётчик оставшихся